# Spring Scheduler is misfiring

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I am using spring scheduler to schedule a Hourly Job after 9AM  daily. This job is supposed to run at 9:45, 10:45... 14:45 and so on till 23:45. The cron expression I am using is 0 45 9/1 1/1 * *.

What I am seeing is that the job is **not always** firing at the right time, and sometime it is skipping an entire interval.

What could I be doing wrong? Below is my setup:

'''

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sm.test")
public class MyTestApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyTestApp.class, args);
    }

 Bean(name = "taskScheduler")
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler(){
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(15);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Scheduler-Thread-");
        return scheduler;
    }
}


@Component
public class TestScheduler {
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestScheduler.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyBean bean1;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 45 9/1 1/1 * *")
    public void schedule(){
        LOG.info("Getting the data...");
        bean1.getData();
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, your cron expression is correct?

You write:

> I am using spring scheduler to schedule a Hourly Job after 9AM daily. This job is supposed to run at 9:45, 10:45... 14:45 and so on till 23:45

In the [spring documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions) about scheduling, its written:

```
 ┌───────────── second (0-59)
 │ ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
 │ │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
 │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
 │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12) (or JAN-DEC)
 │ │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 7)
 │ │ │ │ │ │          (or MON-SUN -- 0 or 7 is Sunday)
 │ │ │ │ │ │
 * * * * * *
```

I haven't tested but it looks like it should be something like:

```
0 45 9-23 * * *
```

Namely:

```
0     - every 0'th second (read, at the beginning of the minute)
45    - every 45th minute of the hour
9-23  - of specified hours in the interval from 9 to 23 inclusive
*     - of any day of the month
*     - of any month
*     - of any day of the week
```

This is one direction to check.

Another direction (not likely but still I mention it as a possible reason, at least it worth mentioning) is:
You have a thread pool of 15 threads to handle scheduled jobs, ok.
What if other parts of the application also use this thread pool? And actually, when the time comes to trigger the task there are no available threads in the pool?

Comment: Thanks @Mark Bramnik. Your version is definitely simpler. 0  45  9/1  1/1  *  * should also work, right? 0[Second] 45[Minute] 9/1 [Start at 9 and then repeat every 1 hour] 1/1 [Start from 1 day of the month and Repeat every 1 day] *  *. I will try out with 0 45 9-23 * * * and update. Also going to increase the pool size. -Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mark, so the run with 0 45 9-23 * * *, did not start at 9:45, but it started at 10:13. The next run was also delayed, from 10:45 to 10:53. But the Job  ran timely at 11:45. Also another Job scheduled by the cron 0 15 15 * * *  did not start at all at 3:15PM.

Comment: In this case further investigation is required. Do you happen to run quartz? Are you running inside the container? Who else uses the thread s allocated for running the scheduled job. Can you for now comment the code of the Job itself so that you’ll be able to test only the infra (maybe the code of the job itself gets stuck for some reason, acquires a lock and no-one else can enter…. Can you take a thread dump right before you’re supposed to run a scheduled job?